# Multiple input field for multiple forms for multiple users

Tags: ruby-on-rails, forms, haml, simple-form

I am trying to create a small accounting system. Here I have some products. Each month I want to write down how many of each product each user bought.

Lets say I have 3 users and 4 products. I want a 3 by 4 table with all the users names on the left and the products on the top. In each field I want to be able to write how many of that particularly item that user bought.

I have tried the following, however the fields are not unique, so only the last one gets submitted. How should I proceed?

```
= simple_form_for(:lines, url: lines_url) do |f|
  - @users.each do |user|
    tr
      td= user.name
      - @products.each do |product|
        td
          = f.fields_for user do |u|
            = u.fields_for product do |p|
              = p.fields_for Line.new do |l|
                = l.text_field :quantity
```

---

EDIT:

I found that this will also work, howver, it is rather hackish:

```
= simple_form_for(:lines, url: lines_url) do |f|
  - @users.each do |user|
    tr
      td= user.name
      - @products.each do |product|
        td
          = text_field :lines, "#{user.id}][#{product.id}"
```

Notice the `][` in the `text_field`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I have had this problem a few times and have come up with this:

```
= simple_form_for(:lines, url: lines_url) do |f|
  - @users.each_with_index do |user, index|
    %tr
      %td= user.name
      - @products.each do |product|
        %td
          = f.fields_for user do |u|
            = u.fields_for index do |u|
              = u.fields_for product do |p|
                = p.fields_for Line.new do |l|
                  = l.text_field :quantity
```

The `fields_for index` means that it comes out as `lines[user][0][product][line]` etc. , which is how Rails usually deals with submitting multiple objects. The params come in as:

```
{
  "0" => some_data,
  "1" => some_other_data
}
```

which is a bit weird but how it is meant to look. I seem to remember having problems with using this technique with as many levels of nesting as you have, but it should help give you some ideas.

Comment: Is this really the correct solution? It seems a bit weird, that I need to care about the index myself.

Comment: I know, it really sucks, but I haven't been able to find anything better. This doesn't seem to be something that Rails deals with very well out of the box, as it's not quite standard single record CRUD stuff.